# How to enable code review functionality in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

Greatings, I have personal gitLab deployed(all settings are by default) on server. It is Community edition, but when my team mate created Merge Request to Project and assigned me as Approval on Changes tab I press on needed code line button to make comment. Popup window appiers, and there I could only left comment not code review itself(does not appiers blue button)

[image: Code review option in gitLab]
Here(Official video from gitLab **Merge Request review - Faster Code Review**) as you can see there is button to start code review. But in my personal  gitLab deployed on server I do not have code Review button.
[image]

What I tried - searching in GitLab documentation to enable "Code Review" functionality, but I did not found the desired setting(?), only how to do Code Review

Question is - How to enable on personal gitLab the functionality of "Code review"?

Comment: Are you on a really old version of GitLab? What version does it say on /help?

Comment: /Help says "GitLab Enterprise Edition 11.3.4-ee 14d3a1d " and tag update ASAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to batch comments on a merge request into a "review" was added in version 11.4 according to the implementation issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/1984

The only solution is to upgrade your GitLab instance.